# How use System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0 in a .net framework 4.0 based application?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

in VS2010 write this code and run:

===========

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), @"Microsoft.NET\Framework");
string pathV2 = Path.Combine(path, "v2.0.50727");
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(pathV2,  System.Windows.Forms.dll")));
Console.Write(assembly.Location);
```

=================
it will write out: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll`

so, how can I use  `System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0`?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just target .NET 3.5 SP1 (which uses the only System.Windows.Forms assembly)?

Or, if you're going to target .NET 4, then why are you trying to *not* target .NET 4?

**Edit 2:** This isn't possible without creating a second assembly that targets .NET 3.5 or earlier.

Comment: I want to use Control.FromHandle function to get control from another application , I must use System.Windows.Forms.dll Version 2.0, if the  target application is base on .net 2.0.

Comment: extern alias  can not resolve this problem
when I add refrence of System.Windows.Forms.dll  from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 , it automatic change to v4.0
from my sample code in question, even I load from byte[] ,it will change to v4.0

Comment: @maskx: The only way to do this is create a second assembly that targets the earlier framework and hide the code in there.

Comment: I have try this way, but failed.careate a assembly base target to fareamework v2.0,  when refrence in an application target to  framework v2.0 , it is v2.0. but when refrence in an application target to faramework v4.0. all the assembly is change to v4.0, include  System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: maybe, this problem can not be resolved, refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/ee518876(en-us,VS.100).aspx#scenarios